# Kusama/Polkadot (v0.9.37) is having memory-leak-like pattern on GCP VMs

Tags: polkadot, kusama, memory

We are using polkadot-v0.9.37 and we are experiencing some memory-leak-like issue on the polkadot/kusama nodes. [image: kusama-0.9.37-gcp-pattern] [image: polkadot-0.9.37-gcp-pattern]
We also host polkadot/kusama nodes on other providers (for example AWS), but it did not seems to have the same pattern.

On GCP we used n1-standard-16 (16 vCPU  60GB Mem) for hosting.

Here's our launch parameters

```
--base-path=/chain-data

--rpc-cors=all

--port=30333

--rpc-port=9933

--ws-port=9944

--ws-external

--rpc-external

--node-key=key_here

--pruning=archive

--rpc-methods=Safe

--name=name_here

--chain=kusama

--db-cache=3500

--in-peers=10000

--out-peers=50
```

Please kindly advise if there's any fix for this issue. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be an issue of Polkadot repository.

Comment: Please open an *issue* here, thanks https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/new